# Does onesignal subscription id work with a player id API

Tags: java, android, node.js, onesignal

In my Java android SDK I'm getting the subscription ID as follows and then sending it to my backend where im storing these subscription IDs in my DB but it doesnt seem to work when I try to send a notification using

```
IUserManager user = OneSignal.getUser();
String subscriptionId = user.getPushSubscription().getId();
```

This is my node js api code snippet

```
notification.app_id = config.ONESIG_APP_ID;
    notification.include_player_ids = subscriptionIds;
    notification.contents = {
      en: message,
    };
    client
      .createNotification(notification)
      .then((result) => {
        resolve(result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        resolve({ status: 'Failure' });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

> The OneSignal ID is UUID generated by OneSignal to represent a user. The OneSignal ID will always be associated with a Subscription ID and/or alias, otherwise it will be deleted.

> A subscription refers to the ways a user can receive messages sent from OneSignal, like push notifications, SMS, and email. These messaging channels are each assigned a Subscription ID to uniquely identify that specific channel. In-app messages do not have a Subscription ID.

You can [Create alias (by subscription)](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-alias-by-subscription) then use the Alias to send message.

[create-notification](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-notification)

> Target specific users by aliases assigned via API. An alias can be an external_id, onesignal_id, or a custom alias.